# MVC 4 RedirectToAction with Model (or something to go back to the old URL)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form with multiple options of criteria, like searching either by a date range, or a specific period, etc

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Report model = new Report();
    //assigning default values, default actions, default everything

    //Index.cshtml exists
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetByDateRange(Report fromPage)
{
    fromPage.DoWhatItMust();

    //"GetByDateRange.cshtml" doesn't exist, so I send back to Index
    return View("Index", fromPage);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetByASpecificDate(Report fromPage)
{
    fromPage.DoWhatYouMustAgain();

    //"GetByASpecifiDate.cshtml" doesn't exist as well, so I send back to Index    
    return View("Index", fromPage);
}
```

This works, but the problem is the URL that goes from `localhost:10500/Project/Report` to `localhost:10500/Project/Report/GetByASpecificDate`.

Is there anyway I can keep the main one or the index one?

I tried `RedirectToAction` but it doesn't accept a model as parameter, so I don't know how I can keep the main URL but calling a different method depending on the user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decorate one of your "GetBy" methods with `[ActionName("Index")]` to have it use the same URL. This will work because the regular `Index` action is GET only, and your "GetBy" actions are POST only. The routing framework can therefore differentiate which to call based on the method of the request. However, since both the "GetBy" methods are POST only, this will only work for one.

What I would actually recommend for you though is to not go with a number of different actions and just have a post version of your `Index` that takes your `Report` model, along with some differentiating parameter. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Report fromPage, string getBy)
{
    if (getBy == "dateRange")
    {
        // do something
    }

    if (getBy == "specificDate")
    {
       // do soemthing else
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to pass some value for `getBy` in your form. The easiest way would probably be to just add a hidden field:

```
@Html.Hidden("getBy", "dateRange")
```

Comment: I can't use `@Html.Hidden()` because the value persists since it's mapped to the property, but using the non-mapped way worked excellent, thanks!